# How to place a UIButton below UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

In Interface Builder, I have a `UITableView` and I want to place a `UIButton` below it. I placed a `UIView` into the lower part of the screen and placed the `UIButton` into it -- I was not able to place the `UIButton` onto the screen without the `UIView`.

Now everything looks good in IB, however, when I run the application, the button is not displayed there although there is enough place below the table. My colleague said me the `UIButton` is probably covered with the table and that he went over this problem by creating the button programatically. But I want to create this button in IB...

Comment: what is the super class of your class?

Comment: UITableViewController (I hope I've got your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my knowledge we cannot add the image to the tableview.So When you are creating the new file,instead of taking the `UITableviewController` if you take the `UIViewController` you can add any elements to the Controller.i.e tableview,on the top of that add button .....I hope this description may be helpful.